# Getting "Cannot read property 'asMutable' of undefined" error even though the page renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm getting the following error when my page renders (client side)

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'asMutable' of undefined`

The page renders correctly though, so I can only assume that the component makes the request again after the render, it's not breaking anything (so far) it's just an annoying error, however as I'm trying to learn React, it would be helpful to know why this was happening.

Here is my code:

```
//nav.jsx

import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { navLoad } from '../../../scripts/actions';

export default class HeaderNav extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(navLoad());
  }

  render() {
    const { nav, isFetching } = this.props;
    const navitems = nav.items.asMutable().map((item) => {
      if(item.inNav === 'header') {
        return <li key={item._id}><Link to={item.slug}>{item.name}</Link></li>
      }
    });
    return(
      <ul class="c-primary-nav">
        { navitems }
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

function select(state) {
  const { nav } = state;
  return {
    nav
  };
}

export default connect(select)(HeaderNav);
```

**2nd component**

```
// socialLinks.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { socialLinksLoad } from '../../../scripts/actions';

export default class SocialLinks extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(socialLinksLoad());
  }

  render() {
    const { socialLinks, isFetching } = this.props;
    const faString = 'fa ';
    console.log('socialLinks', socialLinks.items)
    const slComponents = socialLinks && socialLinks.items ? socialLinks.items.asMutable().map((item) => {
      return <li key={item._id}><a class={faString + item.class} title={item.title} href={item.link}>{item.label}</a></li>
    }) : null;
    if(isFetching) {
      return(
        <section class="loader">
          <span>Content is loading...</span>
        </section>
      )
    } else {
      return(
        <ul class="c-social-links">
          { slComponents }
        </ul>
      )
    }
  }
}

function select(state) {
  const { socialLinks } = state;
  return {
    socialLinks
  };
}

export default connect(select)(SocialLinks);
```

**Also included reducer in case that's related to the issue**

```
// reducer.js
export function socialLinks(state = socialLinksInitialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_SOCIAL_LINKS :
      return Immutable(state).merge({
        items: action.payload.socialLinks,
        isFetching: false
      })
    case REQUEST_SOCIAL_LINKS :
      return Immutable(state).merge({
        isFetching: true
      })
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function nav(state = navInitialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_NAV :
      return Immutable(state).merge({
        items: action.payload.nav,
        isFetching: false
      })
    case REQUEST_NAV :
      return Immutable(state).merge({
        isFetching: true
      })
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  socialLinks,
  nav,
  routing: routerReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The componentWillMount() method is invoked immediately before the initial rendering occurs. For this 1st rendering, the props are already set: nav is an empty object (or undefined), that's why you get the error.

The effect of dispatching navLoad() will happen on the next render, following redux's state change.

[This react-redux issue](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/210#issuecomment-166055644) may give you additional information.

Usually, when you initialize some data for your component from the componentWillMount() or componentDidMount() methods, you just have to take into account the initial "empty" state in your render() method implementation, for the first rendering.

For example in your case, that would simply be something like this:

```
const navitems = nav && nav.items ? nav.items.asMutable().map((item) => {
  if(item.inNav === 'header') {
    return <li key={item._id}><Link to={item.slug}>{item.name}</Link></li>
  }
}) : null;
```

Comment: So do I need to pass the props to the component from the parent component then? That' seems to be the gist of that issue but I might be misunderstanding it.

Comment: No, I just edited my answer to give you a standard pattern for this case.

Comment: Interestingly, this worked perfectly until I repeated the process for a different component. Now it seems that only the last component called on the page will work. I assume that the props or state are being overwritten somehow but I'm not sure where. I've updated my answer to include the 2nd component, can you see where i'm going wrong?

Comment: Excuse me, I don't really understand the problem now. Could you please update your question with the problem (error?) you get now, when and where it happens? Maybe some code from the parent component which calls the HeaderNav and SocialLinks components, too. Thanks!

Comment: I've actually opened another question with more detail as I think you have fixed my initial problem and this one is possibly a whole new issue. I've marked your answer as accepted. The new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777619/state-seems-to-be-getting-overwritten-instead-of-merged