# State seems to be getting overwritten instead of merged

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm currently trying to learn Redux and I think I must be implementing it wrong as only the last component to be rendered on the page actually works. I suspect the state is being overwritten each time.

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKFFDJ3Bmho) tutorial which only uses one example of data retrieval so I have probably just misunderstood how to write to the state.

Here is my reducer. Any ideas where I've gone wrong? Also this all seems very verbose, is there a DRYer way of writing this out?

```
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';

// Import actions
import {
  REQUEST_CONFIG,
  GET_CONFIG,
  REQUEST_PAGES,
  GET_PAGES,
  REQUEST_SOCIAL_LINKS,
  GET_SOCIAL_LINKS,
  REQUEST_NAV,
  GET_NAV
} from './actions';

const configInitialState = Immutable({
  items: [],
  isFetching: false
})

const pagesInitialState = Immutable({
  items: [],
  isFetching: false
})

const socialLinksInitialState = Immutable({
  items: [],
  isFetching: false
})

const navInitialState = Immutable({
  items: [],
  isFetching: false
})

export function config(state = configInitialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CONFIG :
      return Immutable(state).merge({
        items: action.payload.config[0],
        isFetching: false
      })
    case REQUEST_CONFIG :
      return Immutable(state).merge({
        isFetching: true
      })
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function pages(state = pagesInitialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_PAGES :
      return Immutable(state).merge({
        items: action.payload.pages,
        isFetching: false
      })
    case REQUEST_PAGES :
      return Immutable(state).merge({
        isFetching: true
      })
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function socialLinks(state = socialLinksInitialState, action)      {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_SOCIAL_LINKS :
      return Immutable(state).merge({
        items: action.payload.socialLinks,
        isFetching: false
      })
    case REQUEST_SOCIAL_LINKS :
      return Immutable(state).merge({
        isFetching: true
      })
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function nav(state = navInitialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_NAV :
      return Immutable(state).merge({
        items: action.payload.nav,
        isFetching: false
      })
    case REQUEST_NAV :
      return Immutable(state).merge({
        isFetching: true
      })
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  config,
  pages,
  socialLinks,
  nav,
  routing: routerReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Just in case it's required, here is an example of one of my components as well:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { navLoad } from '../../../scripts/actions';

export default class HeaderNav extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(navLoad());
  }

  render() {
    const { nav } = this.props;
    const navitems = nav && nav.items ? nav.items.asMutable().map((item) => {
      if(item.inNav === 'header' || item.inNav === 'both') {
        return <li key={item._id}><Link to={item.slug}>{item.name}</Link></li>
      }
    }) : null;
    if(nav.isFetching) {
      return(
        <section class="loader">
          <span>Content is loading...</span>
        </section>
      )
    } else {
      return(
        <nav class="c-primary-nav">
          <span class="c-primary-nav_toggle">Menu</span>
          <ul>
            { navitems }
          </ul>
        </nav>
      )
    }
  }
}

function select(state) {
  const { nav } = state;
  return {
    nav
  };
}

export default connect(select)(HeaderNav);
```

and here is where the components are called:

```
import React from 'react';
import HeaderNav from './Header/nav.jsx';
import SocialLinks from './Header/socialLinks.jsx';

export default class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <header class="c-global-header" role="banner">
        <HeaderNav />
        <SocialLinks />
      </header>
    )
  }
}
```

Update: I'm still hoping for an answer to this question as it's still stumping me, I've altered the code a little now but to no avail. You can see my full codebase here: https://github.com/alexward1981/portfolio-react (All the relevant stuff is in the 'src' folder)

Comment: Can you explain the problem in more detail? What do you mean when you say "only last component to be rendered works"? What specifically is happening / not working?

Comment: So my page renders out two components, <Nav /> and <SocialLinks /> If Nav is the last component rendered on the page then the data from that is pulled into the state and the component is displayed but SocialLinks is ignored, the opposite is also true. I'm getting no error messages, the first component is just ignored. (I've added the component which calls these components to the question)

Comment: @AlexWard one problem that I see is that you're exporting two members in your file as default exports: `export default class HeaderNav extends React.Component` and `export default connect(select)(HeaderNav);`. Only one should be exported as default (in your case, for sure it's the second one). In TypeScript, you would get an error, but probably using Babel, it simply will export as default the first default exports found in your file, and probably that's why things aren't working for you.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Unfortunately, this hasn't fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm not familiar with seamless-immutable, but your problem may be related to its usage in your reducers. Are you sure that this library really produces new object references when state changes, as it is required by redux? Anyway, you may have to use more code to properly combine redux and seamless-immutable (like https://github.com/eadmundo/redux-seamless-immutable). To simplify things, have you try to use plain JS immutability patterns (with Object.assign(), or object spread syntax for example) instead of seamless-immutable?

Comment: I've not. Maybe I should try that, perhaps I'm getting ahead of myself with the immutable stuff.

Answer (score 6):

I just faced the same problem, the issue was in the reducer, instead of return state in default switch case section, I was return initialState.

```
export const getAppShopReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FETCH_APP_SHOP_SUCCESS:

      return state
        .set('loading', false)
        .set('user', action.payload.user)
        .set('appShop', action.payload.appShop)
        .set('shop', action.payload.shop)
        ;

    case types.FETCH_APP_SHOP_REQUEST:

      return initialState.set('loading', true);

    default:
      return state; // Here's the problem, it was `initialState`;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you want to get new data for a component when the page updates, then the data-fetching in componentWillMount() is not enough (because it's only called on 1st rendering of the component).

You also have to add data-fetching in another component's life-cycle method, componentWillReceiveProps():

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  const { dispatch } = this.props;
  dispatch(navLoad());
}
```

You could add a proper condition (comparing nextProps with this.props) to check if you really need to fetch new data on each update.

Comment: There isn't a secondary page update, all the components are called on the first page load, however only the last component on the page is the one which is actually mounted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with seamless-immutable, but your problem may be related to its usage in your reducers. Are you sure that this library really produces new object references when state changes, as it is required by redux?

Anyway, you may have to use more code to properly combine redux and seamless-immutable, like [this library](http://github.com/eadmundo/redux-seamless-immutable) does.

To simplify things, I think you should try to use plain JS immutability patterns (with Object.assign(), or object spread syntax for example) instead of seamless-immutable. For example, you could write your reducers like this:

```
const navInitialState = {
  items: [],
  isFetching: false
}

function nav(state = navInitialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_NAV :
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload.nav,
        isFetching: false
      }
    case REQUEST_NAV :
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work through my issue by reading through this list in the notes on `combineReducers`

http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html#notes

There are some instances where it automatically fails if `undefined` state isnt handled correctly.

Answer (score -2):

It was a bloody typo after everything which I just never spotted. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: You're welcome ! Glad that you eventually solved your problem. Ciao !

Comment: What was the typo? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: In another page where I import the actions, I accidentally forgot to rename a few of them so they were overwriting previous ones with the wrong data (e.g. blank data)